# Gitlab CI/CD changes rule, needs and invalid yaml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two jobs in my .gitlab-ci.yml file, similar to this:

```yaml
job1:
    stage: build
    script:
        - cd docker/some-dir
        - make build
        - make run
    rules:
        - changes: 
            - "docker/some-dir/**/*"
          when: always
        - when: never

job2:    
    stage: build
    needs:
        - job1
    script:
        - cd docker/some-dir2
        - make build
        - make run
```

- `job1` is builing and pushing `docker_image_1`
- `job2` is building and pushing `docker_image_2`
- `docker_image_2` is based on `docker_image_1` e.g. the Dockerfile starts with `FROM: docker_image_1`
- I want to rebuild `docker_image_1` only if something was changed under docker/some-dir
- this is a monorepo, and I want it that way
- If I delete the `rules` section from `job1` then there is no error, but of course then it rebuilds `docker_image_1` for all push events, and I want to avoid that.

GitLab pipline gives me "yaml error" without any detailed error message. I have already checked the reference https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules but I cannot figure this out.

Why is it invalid?

What I want to achieve is this:

- if something changes under docker/some-dir then run the `job1` (this includes any CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE with a push operation)
- OR if the pipeline was started for any other reason without a push event (e.g. started manually, or scheduled etc.) then also run `job1`
- otherwise do not run `job1`
- and finally, run `job2` (even if `job1` was not run)

Comment: A few points here. if job 2 should run regardless of job1 then remove the needs, unless what you mean is run job2 after job1, unless there is no job 1 then run job 2 anyway. If thats what you want then look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsoptional. for your invalid yaml issue, you must not be showing everything cause pasting this yaml in gitlab pipeline editor says its valid syntax.

Comment: Actually, that was the root cause of the problem. Finally I found an error message: 'job2' job needs 'job1' job, but 'job1' is not in any previous stage. Adding optional: true solved the error message. you can post your comment as an answer and I'm going to accept it. The most interesting thing to me is that on the pipeline list page, this error shows up as "yaml invalid". I think that error message is wrong. The yaml is not invalid, because it works in some cases (e.g. when job1 ran) and not in other cases. And yes, the built-in pipeline editor also does not mark this as "invalid yaml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While at the time I didnt know it was the root cause, in my comment I suggested using the needs:optional attribute in job2. From the comments you confirmed this did indeed solve the issue so adding it as an answer for completeness.

The needs keyword requires that before job2 can run job1 must have run. Job2 in your case has not rules and will always run, however job1 has certain rules that means it doesnt run in all cases. In the pipelines where job1 has not run job2 will try to run but should get an error similar to `'job1' job needs 'job2' job, but it was not added to the pipeline`. Sometimes this is not evident from within the UI.

Using the optional attribute allows you to define that job2 should wait until job1 is finished, however if there is no job1 then job2 can just run anyway. The example from the gitlab docs is

```yaml
build-job:
  stage: build

test-job1:
  stage: test

test-job2:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - job: test-job2
      optional: true
    - job: test-job1
  environment: production

review-job:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - job: test-job2
      optional: true
  environment: review
```

for more details you can read https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsoptional